# Revel framework caching static files?

Tags: web, go, revel

I am trying to build a simple web app on the revel go web framework.
For some reason, files in the public directory are not loaded correctly when I open their URLs in the browser. For example, an older version of the file may appear (even after reloading in the browser), or a truncated version shows up.

Anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: Try a `curl -I http://url/to/file.jpg` and see if a `Cache-Control` or `Expires` header is being set (or check the source code).

Comment: I tried it and I get the following output:
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=droparea.css
Content-Length: 645
Content-Type: text/css; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 05 Aug 2013 23:03:46 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 05 Aug 2013 23:02:51 GMT
Set-Cookie: REVEL_FLASH=; Path=/
Set-Cookie: REVEL_SESSION=56490577f9ae482388651378bc5c746a230c35fe-%00_TS%3A1378335826%00; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 04 Sep 2013 23:03:46 UTC`

Comment: Additionally, curl retrieves an old version of the file. Restarting revel doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: There is an `Expires` header in there. You're not in my timezone (so I can't figure out if it's in the 'future' for you) but if the date provided by Expires is > than the time, your browser will cache the files and not check until that time is exceeded as there is no requirement to re-validate.

You could always force a hard reload (Ctrl/Cmd+R) in your browser as an interim measure, or version your CSS: `droparea.css?v={{ time.Now().UTC() }}`

Comment: Interestingly, the expires date is in the past. I also tried changing code and hot reload doesn't seem to work even though i'm running in dev mode.. something's fishy here

Comment: It may be related to this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/revel-framework/hTFmGQFxj0g/ECE4T4wnoX0J

Comment: You can get around that if you mount the shared folder via NFS in your Vagrantfile :)

Comment: Btw, what really surprises me is that curl returns an old version of the file even after restarting revel. Where is it caching that old version?

Answer (score 0):

- Is GOPATH set up in the same location you are developing?
- Are more copies of that file in your gopath?
- Could you try to run `strace -e open revel run my/app/name | grep file.jpg` and see what is the location that revel is using?

I had a similar problem because I develop outside my gopath...